# Excel Power Pivot Data Model

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a problem in creating correct model for my excel power pivot. Here is how my current data model relationships look like:

[image: relationships]

And I'm trying to make a pivot table containg Rows, Columns and Values from tables „PH“ and „IMS“, with Filters from the table „BU_Brick“.

[image: pivot data]

Untill I add Filters, everything works fine, but when I add Filters from „BU_Brick“ table the following worning shows up:

[image: warning]

And now I'm very confused. Which else relationships do I need?
Of course, data in pivot doesn't change on filtering.

Comment: Can you add in a screenshot of the actual relationships you've created? For example, [Brand].[Brand] = [BU_Brick].[Brand]. Also, which table is the "Brand" field, that you're filtering on, coming from?

Comment: [Brand].[Brand] = [BU_Brick].[Brand];  
[Brand].[Brand] = [PH].[Brand];  
[PH].[Product] = [IMS].[Product];  
[IMS].[Brick] = [Brick].[Brick];  
[Brick].[Brick] = [BU_Brick].[Brick];  
  
Everything in filter is from BU_Brick table.

Comment: Try using the immediate Brick and Brand fields in the Brick and Brand tables as your filters. I've experienced the same problem in PowerPivot when trying to filter on fields that are more than one table away (can't explain why).

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, and that works fine, but there's still a problem with the other two fields - Manager and Associate

Comment: I would suggest creating two more intermediate dimension tables, like Brick and Brand, to house the unique Manager and Associate values. You can then filter on these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model has no connection between BU_Brick and IMS tables. When you filter BU_Brick, PowerBI has no way of passing these filters to the IMS table.

One way of solving this issue is to change the connection between BU_Brick and Brick to bi-directional. Double-click the connection, and when "connection edit" window opens, change flter direction to "both":

[image]

The little arrow on the connector will change to dowble-arrow, and BU_Brick filters will now work.

Formally speaking, you need to enable a flow of filter context in many-to-many relations. This is a common situation, and here you can learn more:

[Many-to-many relationships in Power BI and Excel 2016](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/many-to-many-relationships-in-power-bi-and-excel-2016/)

Comment: Thank you, but I use Excel Power Pivot, not Power BI
And Excel Power Pivot allows only 1:N relationships

Comment: Several things then:

1) It would be helpful if you mention the software you use, including its version (Excel 2016?)

2) The link I posted will still help you, it contains the solution for PowerPivot too;

3) You should revisit the design of BU_Brick table. It's a "bridge" table that should only contain Brand and Brick keys; everything else (Manager, etc) should be moved to dimensions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this approach.

Comment: Thank you once more! I read the article, applied this approach, and it helped. Also, I've noticed that I had to hide all except calculated fields in IMS table, in order to not display the warning with relationships. Why is it so?

Comment: I think you will keep getting the warning as long as you use any field from BU_Brick table as a filter. I would use instead Brand from table Brand, Brick from table Brick, and as I mentioned before, I would redesign tables so that Associate and Manager are not part of BU_Brick table. Then your warnings should go away.

Comment: But warning went away when I hid all except measures in IMS table. Ok, I've also put crossfilter fn from the example, and now filtration actually works :)
Anyway, I also tried to reconstruct the example from your article, and there was also this warning until I hid everything except measures in Balances table.

Comment: I have a similar situation, mentioned here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74483229/excel-data-model-relationship-not-working).  In the article you mention, I can't figure out, where exactly in Power pivot do i Need to write the formulas? @RADO

Comment: @SurenGrigoryan: 
You need to write a DAX measure and put it into the pivot table first. Then add fields to the row area. Without a measure, Excel attempts to list all items.

Comment: Thank you @RADO. That is exactly my question, how do I put DAX measure into the pivot table? I will probably be able to replicate the formula used in the article, but not sure where to start with?

Comment: @SurenGrigoryan - if you are very new to PowerPivot and DAX, I highly recommend to read at least one good book first, or take a class. It's a complex software which is very hard to master without proper training.